# sqlite (with c++). import from string instead of csv file?

Tags: c++, sqlite

problem: in c++, using sqlite, im looking for a way to insert multiple rows into a table, directly from a string containing multiple "rows".

i would like to "reformulate" the following statement for insertion into a table T

```
INSERT into T VALUES(row1); // 1st row insertion.
INSERT into T VALUES(row2); // 2nd row insertion.
```

i am seeking to substitute it with something like

```
INSERT into T mycsvvals; // std::string mycsvvals contains 2 csv-rows
```

where mycsvvals is a string read-in from a CSV file, "containing" 2 rows of comma separated values.

i could parse the string first, put contents into an array and loop the inserts. however, im wondering if sqlite already provides an efficient bulk import/insert from a *string*, instead of but similar to import/insert from a csv file.

please, can you provide any links/info that will allow me to achieve this?

thx

Comment: We love that you're here and you need to show us your code so we can help you. We can't write it for you.

Comment: @nicomp. no code. im completely green in sqlite. i seek to know that which is clearly specified in the question. the "code" in my question is only meant to examplify what i aim to achieve. if you dont understand the question, please let me know what is the issue so that i may clarify and edit. and, im not asking you to write the code, you may provide a link to useful info, if you understand the question, that is... searched google for an hour or so... :-O thx

Comment: Bulk insert workflow: Prepare an insert statement and begin a transaction. Then for each line you read from the file, extract the fields, bind them to the statement, call `sqlite3_step()` and `sqlite3_reset()`, repeat till done. Commit the transaction, finalize the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer provided by @Shawn was not what i was hoping for in terms of brevity; it is not possible to bulk insert directly from a csv-string, some looping structure *is* necessary. but, in terms of efficiency, its the recommended way to go. thanks @Shawn. the full "prescription" for "prepared statements" in sqlite is given and examplified here:

http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/